# Change the variable value FOR in PHP with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to learn JavaScript and I would like to create a little calculator COC site.
I would know if it's possible to edit a PHP variable in Javascript ?

Here is my HTML/PHP code:

In this part, in the "HDV" div, I just put 10 buttons, when I click on one, go on my JS function who display the second div named "niv caserne" and in this second div, I would change the value of the variable "$i" which is located in the for in the PHP in my JS function.
For example, if I click on the button 1, my JS function will display my div "niv caserne" and the FOR go from 1 to 1, but if I click on the button 2, my JS function displays my div "niv caserne" too but the FOR go from 1 to 2, etc..

```
<body>
<!-- Page Content -->
<div id="container">
    <div id="HDV">
        <p>Hotel De Ville: 
            <?php
                for ($i=1; $i <= 10 ; $i++)
                { 
                    ?>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="<?php echo "HDV_$i" ?>" onclick="infosHDV(<?php echo $i ?>)"><?php echo $i ?></button>
                    <?php
                }
            ?>
        </p>
    </div>

    <!-- HIDE ALL OF THIS OR DISABLE BEFORE USER CHOOSE A TOWN
         WHEN HE CHOOSE A TOWN, CALCULATE AND DISPLAY ONLY THE RIGHT INFORMATION -->
    <div id="niv caserne" style="display:none">
        <p>Niveau des casernes:
            <?php
                for ($i=1; $i <= 4 ; $i++)
                { 
                    ?>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                            <option>6</option>
                            <option>7</option>
                            <option>8</option>
                            <option>9</option>
                            <option>10</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            ?>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Here is my JS function:

```
    <script>
    function infosHDV(nivHDV)
    {
        switch (nivHDV)
        {
            case 1:
                if(document.getElementById('niv caserne').style.display=='block')
                {
                    document.getElementById('niv caserne').style.display='none';
                    //Change the value of the "$i" in the FOR --> 1 from 1
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById('niv caserne').style.display='block';
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if(document.getElementById('niv caserne').style.display=='block')
                {
                    document.getElementById('niv caserne').style.display='none';
                    //Change the value of the "$i" in the FOR --> 1 from 2
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById('niv caserne').style.display='block';
                }
                break;
            case 3:
    ...
                break;
    }
}
    </script>
```

Comment: php runs on the server, javascript runs on the client. you cannot have JS change anything in PHP, other than by doing an http request (e.g. ajax).

Comment: NO WAY to do this without doing an HTTP request

Comment: As said before, you can't change anything in `PHP` with `JavaScript` as PHP runs server-side and JavaScript is client-side. But as you are `NOT` connecting to the database, you could build the `for` in javascript instead of PHP so then, you would have control over it.

Comment: Ok thx, i do this in JS end send to my html code with xxx.innerHTML = "for $i..." :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function generatebtn()
{
var btnHtml = '';
for (i=1; i <= 10 ; i++)
{ 
btnHtml="<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  value="'+i+'"onclick="infosHDV("'+i+'")">"'+i+'"</button>";                   
}
```

You can use javascript for loop instead of php.like above and call generatebtn() in footer.
Do the same thing for other loop and defined  global variable for second loop [better to rename (i) variable] and so when you want change (i) variable value you can change it /overwrite it